# Write a SQL query for enrollments

Tags: sql, t-sql

Here is the question:

Create a table with the following  enrollments

```
Member    Enrl_Start_Date    Enrl_End_Date
M1              1-1-2017                  11-20-2017
M1              12-31-2017                02-01-2018
M1              02-15-2018                04-30-2018
M1              06-10-2018                12-31-2018
M2              1-1-2017                  11-20-2017
M2              12-31-2017                02-01-2018
M3              02-15-2018                04-30-2018
M3              06-10-2018                12-31-2018
M4              1-1-2017                  11-20-2017
M4              12-31-2017                02-01-2018
M5              02-15-2018                04-30-2018
M5              06-10-2018                12-31-2018
```

1. Write a generic SQL that produces the number of members enrolled in 2018 (any one day in 2018)
2. Write a generic SQL that produces the number of days each member is enrolled in 2018
3. Write a generic SQL that produces  the members that are enrolled on ‘12-31-2018’

I have created a sample table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Enrollments](
[Member] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Enrl_Start_Date] [date] NULL,
[Enrl_End_Date] [date] NULL
);
```

Then, I inserted the provided values into dbo.Enrollments.

After doing online research, I was able to write below queries. They seem fine to me but again I am not sure though if I am going in the right way. Any suggestions, please? That will be a real help!!

1. Write a generic SQL that produces the number of members enrolled in 2018 (any one day in 2018)

```
select Member,  count(*) as TotalEnrollments
from [dbo].[Enrollments] 
where year([Enrl_Start_Date])=2018
group by Member
```

Output:

```
Member  TotalEnrollments
M1      2
M3      2
M5      2
```

2. Write a generic SQL that produces the number of days each member is enrolled in 2018

```
select [Member],datediff(day,[Enrl_Start_Date],[Enrl_End_Date]) as TotalEnrolledDays 
from [dbo].[Enrollments]
where year(enrl_start_date)=2018
```

Output:

```
Member  TotalEnrolledDays
M1      74
M1      204
M3      74
M3      204
M5      74
M5      204
```

3. Write a generic SQL that produces  the members that are enrolled on ‘12-31-2018’

```
select count(*) as TotalEnrolledMembers
from [dbo].[Enrollments] 
where [Enrl_Start_Date]= '2018-12-31'
```

Output:

```
TotalEnrolledMembers
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your queries are partially correct.

1. Write a generic SQL that produces the number of members enrolled in 2018 (any one day in 2018)

You dont need to group the query based on `[dbo].[Enrollments].Members`. You can simply return the results as

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS 'Number of Members enrolled in 2018'  
  FROM [dbo].[Enrollments] 
 WHERE year([Enrl_Start_Date])=2018
```

2. You are missing a part of members who are enrolled in 2017, but had their enrollment till 2018. Your query is just looking for the members who started their enrollment in 2018. You will need to expand your query here.

`SELECT [Member], 
DATEDIFF(day,
    CASE
        WHEN YEAR(Enrl_Start_Date) < 2018
        THEN '2018-01-01'
        ELSE Enrl_Start_Date
    END,
    CASE
        WHEN YEAR([Enrl_End_Date]) > 2018
        THEN '2018-12-31'
        ELSE [Enrl_End_Date]
    END) AS TotalEnrolledDays
FROM [dbo].[Enrollments]
WHERE YEAR(enrl_start_date) = 2018
OR YEAR(Enrl_End_Date) = 2018;`

You have members who enrolled from 2017-12-31 to 2018-02-01. The query you had initially will ignore these members (even though they have their enrollment in 2018). So, you will have to consider those members as well.

> CASE    WHEN YEAR(Enrl_Start_Date) < 2018    THEN '2018-01-01'    ELSE
>   Enrl_Start_Date   END,

-- If their enrollement starts in 2017 (and ends in 2018), start date should be 01/01/2018, because you dont want to count the days in 2017

> CASE
>       WHEN YEAR([Enrl_End_Date]) > 2018
>       THEN '2018-12-31'
>       ELSE [Enrl_End_Date]

--If their enrollment (begins in 2018 and) ends in 2019, you dont want to count the days from 2019. So, you will just have end date to be 31/12/2018

3. This query is fine, but you dont need to do `Select Count(*)`, just `Select Count(1)` should be enough

Comment: Happy to help. If this solves your problem, you can accept my answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers